# Mock a module that returns a function and test that this function was called

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to test a React component that, internally, uses a custom hook (Jest used). I successfully mock this hook but I can't find a way to test the calls on the functions that this hook returns.

**Mocked hook**

```
const useAutocomplete = () => {
  return {
    setQuery: () => {}
  }
}
```

**React component**

```
import useAutocomplete from "@/hooks/useAutocomplete";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { setQuery } = useAutocomplete();

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery({});
  }, [])
  ...
}
```

**Test**

```
jest.mock("@/hooks/useAutocomplete");

it("sets the query with an empty object", () => {
  render(<MyComponent />);

  // I want to check the calls to setQuery here
  // e.g. mockedSetQuery.mock.calls
});
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

I currently made the useAutocomplete hook an external dependency:

```
import useAutocomplete from "@/hooks/useAutocomplete";

const MyComponent = ({ autocompleteHook }) => {
  const { setQuery } = autocompleteHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery({});
  }, [])
  ...
}

MyConsole.defaultProps = {
 autocompleteHook: useAutocomplete
}
```

And then I test like this:

```
const mockedSetQuery = jest.fn(() => {});

const useAutocomplete = () => ({
  setQuery: mockedSetQuery,
});

it("Has access to mockedSetQuery", () => {
  render(<MyComponent autocompleteHook={useAutocomplete} />);

  // Do something

  expect(mockedSetQuery.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `useAutocomplete`'s `setQuery` method to validate if it's invoked.

```
jest.mock("@/hooks/useAutocomplete");

it("sets the query with an empty object", () => {
  const useAutocompleteMock = jest.requireMock("@/hooks/useAutocomplete");
  const setQueryMock = jest.fn();
  useAutocompleteMock.setQuery = setQueryMock;
  render(<MyComponent />);

  // The mock function is called twice
  expect(setQueryMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem here is that the useAutocomplete hook is a function. setQuery is not a method of useAutocomplete, it's a method of an object that gets returned from useAutocomplete when you call it.
What I can't figure out how to do, is to have a reference of a mocked function returned by useAutocomplete

Comment: what about if you update the mock as `useAutocompleteMock = jest.fn(() => { setQuery = setQueryMock; });`?

Comment: In that case, the component in-test will call the real useAutocomplete module and not the mocked one